# Jenkins pipelines from SCM in different branch not working

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working with pipelines in Jenkins in a environment which already has configured a pipeline script from SCM which then uses a groovy file for the stages/jobs inside the pipeline. This scripts are on Bitbucket in a master branch.

Every time jenkins jobs starts it call master branch and it runs with no problem and the stages of the pipeline are run.

Now I created a new branch on bitbucket and modified the groovy file to include some more steps (like running unit tests and some more stuff) and I would like that jenkins runs that script but with the branch I specified (the one I created).

Thing is that eventhough I specified my branch in in "branch specifier",  jenkins still runs the master branch. Here are some images of what I have configured.
How can I specify the branch  I want to be run on the pipeline script from SCM?

[image]
[image]

```
Lightweight checkout support not available, falling back to full checkout.
Checking out git git@bitbucket.xxxxxx/xxxxxx.git into /data/jobs/extractor-pipeline-test-dev/workspace@script to read extractor-dev/Jenkinsfile
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx.git
 > /usr/bin/git init /data/jobs/extractor-pipeline-test-dev/workspace@script # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:xxxx/xxxxxx.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxx/deploy.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:xxxxx/deploy.git # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxxx/deploy.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:xxxxx/deploy.git
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:grydev/gp_deploy.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
**Seen branch in repository origin/DEVOPS-568-pipeline-ci
Seen branch in repository origin/dev
Seen branch in repository origin/master**
Seen 3 remote branches
 > /usr/bin/git tag -l # timeout=10
Checking out Revision e3270789a8181b26464f878bfccdf39b3fdabcb0 (master)
Commit message: " ....."
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f e3270789a8181b26464f878bfccdf39b3fdabcb0
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list e3270789a8181b26464f878bfccdf39b3fdabcb0 # timeout=10
```

This is the groovy file, but groovy files  does steps of the code that will be deployed. It doesn't  run any jenkin script. Where it says "master" is of maser code to be deploy and not the deploy script.

Groovy file:

```
def call(body) {

    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()

    def artifactName = 'imp'
    def artifactExt = '.war'
    def artifactVersion = '0.0.1'

    def buildPath = 'target/'
    def warFile = artifactName + '-' + artifactVersion + artifactExt
    def warPath = buildPath + warFile
    def warNoVersion = artifactName + artifactExt

    def deployPath = '/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/'
    def deployFile = deployPath + warNoVersion

    node {
        // Clean workspace before doing anything
        //deleteDir()

        try {

            stage ('Code Checkout') {
                git branch: 'master',
                    credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxxxx/xxxximporter'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: everything looks fine...have you verified the commit id in the console output ?...can you share the console output by hiding the confidential information..

Comment: there I edited it and add that. 3 branches are seen, but master is run. I want that job run my branch "DEVOPS-568-pipeline-ci"

Comment: I include the part where starts running the master branch job. then job run successfully an pipeline ends ok but only wit master branch

Comment: can you share the pipeline script where the "checkout scm" is happening ?

Comment: the script only contains this:
@Library("gp-extractor-deploy") _

DeployExtractor {
    confiFileId = "extractor-conf.properties"
    serverIp = 'x.x.x.x'
    slackChannel = '#xxxxx'
}
which call a groovy file in which all jobs/steps are run

Comment: I added the 2 plug ins neccesarry for this. this is ow I have it configured. Shouldn't I have a drop down menu with the 3 branches that are in git? (mater, dev and mine DEV-OPS568....)

Comment: check lattest images

Comment: looks fine, any issues?

Comment: the dropdown doesn´t show all the branches. I think that´s the issue and investigating why they don´t appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the exactly same issue here, and tried many times. It turned out that the Jenkinsfile specified in script path, is only obtained from git default url, never use the branch we specified in `Branch to build`.

To avoid this, I have to use multiple branch pipeline....

Answer (score 3):

The issue is even though the Jenkinsfile is from the required branch, code checkout is happening through "master" branch. **The reason is code checkout is from branch "master" in "code checkout stage"**. Change the code as follows:

```
try {
    stage ('Code Checkout') {
        git branch: 'REQUIRED BRANCH',
            credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxxxx/xxxximporter'
```

An alternative and rather better option is to provide **GIT BRANCH as parameter from the Jenkins job**. Snapshot below.

[image]

**UPDATE:
This can be achieved by installing the [git parameter plugin.](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin)**

and add the following co**de snippet in your "code checkout" stage** and change accordingly. Here **"gitbranch" is the parameter that you are passing from build**.

```
 checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: gitbranch]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,    
extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '********', url: '**********']]]
```

Comment: ry {
    stage ('Code Checkout') {
        git branch: 'REQUIRED BRANCH',
            credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxxxx/xxxximporter' 
this code is of the Code to deploy, no the code of the script that makes the deploy. I will check te second part of you suggestion

Comment: An alternative and rather better option is to provide GIT BRANCH as parameter from the Jenkins job. Snapshot below. 

Why I don´t have that option in Jenkins? is this a plug in or something I have to add? thanks

Comment: @Guillermo-Casco : If new update is working, mark the answer as accepted/upvote the answer as it helps others when they face the similar issue..

Comment: It didn't yet, I was working on this last friday and with new configuration and new plug in I added and were suggested,   job still runs on master.  I was checking Jenkins configuration to see if there is something different. will check and let you know.

Comment: still running master :( It sees 3 braches but runs only master. Here is the image as I have it now configured.
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxx/deploy.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxx/deploy.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/DEVOPS-568-pipeline-ci
Seen branch in repository origin/dev
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 3 remote branches
 > /usr/bin/git show-ref --tags -d # timeout=10
Checking out Revision ccdf39b3fdabcb0 (master)

Comment: can you paste the checkout code which you are using currently..in your question, not in comments, very difficult to debug in comments section..

Comment: sorry this is all messy. I creaed new question with images which describes more the issue.
Here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262981/jenkins-git-parameter-plug-in-always-run-master-instead-of-choosen-branch

Comment: That is it. There are many other branches which don't have `Jenkinsfile`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, no one way mentioned above was helpful.

It seems that Git parameter plugin passes branch as 'origin/<...>' which does not transform to a valid refspec according to log:

```
> git fetch --tags --force --progress -- ssh://git@***************/group/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/devel^{commit}" # timeout=10
> git rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/refs/heads/origin/devel^{commit}" # timeout=10
> git rev-parse "refs/heads/origin/devel^{commit}" # timeout=10
```

I was not able to use Jenkinsfile with "refs/tags/${TAG}".

Also, when "Lightweight checkout" is unchecked, job always fails with '<...>@script\Jenkinsfile not found'.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Branch specifier' click on the 'add branch' and put your selected branch again. This worked for me even with an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

For my workflow, I:

1. Developed my Jenkinsfile in a different branch
2. I configured Pipeline script from SCM to refer to that branch during development
3. When finished, I merged the Jenkinsfile to the master branch
4. I tried to update the Pipeline script from SCM to go back to the master branch but it kept on getting file not found errors
5. After some degree of troubleshooting, I found that I needed to uncheck "Lightweight checkout"

[image: uncheck-lightweight-checkout]